# Need Table Values as Column Titles

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a table like:

**Survey Result**

```
SurveyId Int ex. 12
QuestionName Varchar ex. A18a
QuestionValue Int ex. 2
```

I am trying to write a query that would set the values of QuestionName as columns horizontally, by SurveyId. If there is no entry for a certain question, that value would read NULL. The result would look like:

```
SurveyId | A01 | A02 | A03 | A04...
12 | 1 | 4 | 3 | NULL...
213 | 2 | 5 | NULL | NULL ...
```

I can't figure out how to select the questions as column titles. Is there an easy way of accomplishing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This basically *is* a pivot table.

A nice tutorial on how to archive this can be found here: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

I advise reading this post and adapt this solution to your needs.